# magento How to rewrite the custom mdoule urls

Tags: magento, url-rewriting, custom-url

I have created the custom module to shops in different country states and city so i have to rewrite the url of module 
from this url http://domain1.com/magento/index.php/shops/index/viewcountry/country/IN/   to 
this url 
http://domain1.com/magento/index.php/India-sarees-shops.html
 below is my code for urlrewrite

```
<?php 

        $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
        Mage::getModel('core/url_rewrite')
        ->setIsSystem(0)
        ->setStoreId($storeId)   
        ->setOptions('RP')  
        ->setIdPath('viewcountry/country/' .$country['value'])
        ->setTargetPath($country['label'].'-sarees-shops.html')
        ->setRequestPath('shops/index/viewcountry/country/'.$country['value'].'/')
        ->save(); 
?>
```

Also getting " ID Path for Specified Store, Request Path for Specified Store already exist "  error please Help me

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
->setIdPath('viewcountry/country/'.$country['value'].'_'.time())
```

This randomizes `id_path` and it will still redirect from `requested_path` to `target_path`.

Comment: I am getting error ID Path for Specified Store, Request Path for Specified Store already exist  and  Redirecting working but getting 404 eror for destination  http://domain1.com/magento/index.php/India-sarees-shops.html so please suggest me ... Thanks in advance

Comment: That means that you already have a rewrite with that request path. Search in your rewrite management grid for `shops/index/viewcountry/country/IN` request path and delete it.

Comment: yes i also deleted but getting the error . can you suggest me the any other way to do the rewrite the urls in magento ?